# Custom tab indicator in android

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

Is there any way to make this custom tab indicator

and tab layout as shown in this screenshot

[image]

Comment: But you can simply add a view below that button set visibility according to view pager's page change.
So it will be easily achievable rather than create a custom tab behavior.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it on your own. Please refer below link for creating your own `CustomTab` view. In below link you need to customize `custom_tab.xml` for getting what you wanted.

https://mobikul.com/make-custom-tabs-icons-android/